# What is the penalty for stealthing at normal speed?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, skills, stealth

In both Pathfinder and D&D 3.5e, the rules for stealthing ([Stealth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/stealth), [Hide](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/hide.htm) and [Move Silently](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/moveSilently.htm)) state:

> When moving at a speed greater than half but **less than** your normal
>   speed, you take a –5 penalty. It’s practically<sup>1</sup>
>   impossible to [use stealth] while attacking, running or charging.

However, none of the rules make any mention about stealthing at normal speed. It is neither impossible, nor is a penalty given. Is there any errata or obscure rule for either system which gives a more official ruling?

<sup>1 - Pathfinder rules say it's impossible, and D&D rules say it's *practically* impossible, imposing a -20 penalty.</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The specificity of the Pathfinder rules imply it's impossible to move your normal speed while stealthing, in addition to while attacking, running, or charging.

Note that Paizo is currently playtesting [new Stealth rules](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5lckz) that cover this situation:

> You can move up to half your normal speed and use Stealth at no penalty. When moving at a speed greater than half and up to your normal speed, you take a –5 penalty.

Comment: I think applying the -5 penalty to moving your normal speed is a good rule. It certainly makes more sense than arbitrarily forcing your players to move just 5' less than their normal speed while sneaking.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say okeefe is probably right about Pathfinder (though a cutoff between moving your speed and your speed-1 seems silly). My suggestion, would be to either continue the -5 at normal speed, or if you feel the need up it to a -10 penalty (double the 'slower' movement penalty, but half that of running).

Answer (score 1):

Under PF for the Rogue class (page 68 of the Core rules):
Fast Stealth (Ex): This ability allows a rogue to move at full speed using the Stealth skill without penalty.

As others have said, from greater-than-half-speed to less-than-full-speed, the penalty is -5.
Personally, I have run it as -5 for (51% to 75%) speed and -10 for (76-100%) speed ... unless the character has Fast Stealth.